# No permanent ids in re-route (HERE Android Premium SDK)

Tags: here-api

I use Here Android Premium SDK to get a route from the online backend, using CoreRouter::calculateRoute(). To enhance the route with additional data, I use the route links' permanent ids to query HERE's Platform Data Extension (PDE). This breaks when a re-route is necessary, since the updated route does not contain permanent ids.

The original route contains each link's directed permanent id, which I access like this:

```
fun handleRoute(route: Route) {
  for (item in route.routeElements.elements) {
    val pid = item.roadElement.permanentDirectedLinkId
  }
}
```

Permanent ids are of type Long and can be positive/negative depending on the travel direction, like -1199076058.

When the driver deviates from the calculated route (e.g. doesn't follow a suggested maneuver), a new route is calculated automatically and received via

```
NavigationManagerEventListener::onRouteUpdated(Route)
```

For this updated route, all permanent ids are 0. The same happens when using `RerouteListener::onRerouteEnd(RouteResut)` instead, and also does not change when I request `roadElement.permanentLinkId` (without the `Directed`). Only local ids are available (`roadElement.identifier`).

At the moment I'm using a workaround where the re-route event triggers a new route request. This kindof works, but is not a clean solution.

I would expect the same fields filled when re-routing as when routing. How can I get the permanent ids also for the re-routed result?

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can you please give me the Android SDK release number you are currently using?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Should be Android Premium SDK 3.10

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Just for the record: still the same on latest SDK 3.11

Comment: We tried to reproduce the issue and got no success.
It was tested 3.10, 3.11 and last master - everything works ok.
We need to gig a little bit deeper here. Could you provide more information? Settings for route and/or further sample code?

Answer (score 0):

As stated clearly in our documentation:

> getPermanentDirectedLinkId() The Permanent Link ID (stable across
> different map versions) of the RoadElement with travel direction:
> positive sign (+) means driving in the 'canonical' direction of the
> road and negative sign (-) means driving against the 'canonical'
> direction of the road.
>
> getPermanentLinkId() Returns the Permanent
> Link ID (stable across different map versions) of the RoadElement.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/index.html

So, the link IDs for route updates should not be null or 0 as in new routes.
You may also upgrade to the new SDK version.